# JavaScript function syntax error in Internet Explorer 10 + 11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this script to display/hide some divs.
It works perfectly in all browsers except for Internet Explorer 10+11. I get a syntax error in this line: `const show = () =>`".

The code is this:

```
function cycle(info) {
  let i = 0,
    blocks = Object.keys(info);
  const show = () =>
    $("#" + blocks[i % blocks.length])
    .fadeIn(300)
    .delay(info[blocks[i++ % blocks.length]])
    .fadeOut(300, show);
  show();
}

//Run
cycle({
  block2: 7000,
  block3: 3000
});
```

[**JsFiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/muvghs9v/1/).

Can it be fixed so that it works in IE10+11 too?

Comment: Really what you should be doing is use babel to transpile the code down.

Comment: You should update the title to reflect the actual problem. The problem isn't with `const`, but with the arrow function.

Comment: You are right. I edited the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example (tested on IE 11)

```js
function cycle(info) {
  let i = 0,
    blocks = Object.keys(info);
  const show = function() {
    $("#" + blocks[i % blocks.length])
      .fadeIn(300)
      .delay(info[blocks[i++ % blocks.length]])
      .fadeOut(300, show);
  }
  show();
}

cycle({
  block2: 7000,
  block3: 3000
});
```

```css
#block2,
#block3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block2">
  <div>Block 2</div>
</div>
<div id="block3">
  <div>Block 3</div>
</div>
```

The problem you had was the way you were defining your `const show`. I am assuming IE doesn't recognise the way, so the simplest fix was to change that to the normal way, i.e `smth = function(){}`. This fixed the issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works perfectly in IE10+11 now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @meek may I ask you to upvote and mark the answer as Accepted, so that future visitors can find and solve their issue faster? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have two issues here. Firstly IE doesn't support arrow functions at all. Secondly, the `const` keyword is only supported in IE11+, so IE10 and lower would be an issue there.

To fix this you'll need to amend your logic to work around those restrictions, like this:

```
function cycle(info) {
  let i = 0,
    blocks = Object.keys(info);

  var show = function() {
    $("#" + blocks[i % blocks.length])
      .fadeIn(300)
      .delay(info[blocks[i++ % blocks.length]])
      .fadeOut(300, show);
  }

  show();
}
```

Comment: As a side note, using a bundler/minifier with ES6 flags set can do this for deployed code automatically. Check out UglifyJS.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda expressions (or some call them "fat arrow expressions") are not supported in IE 10 or 11.

You can instead use the old and simple way of writing function expressions:

Instead of:

```
() => {}
```

use:

```
function(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
function timeSet(){
$("#block3").fadeIn();
$("#block2").hide();
}
setInterval(timeSet,7000);
function timeSet1(){
$("#block3").hide();
$("#block2").fadeIn();
}
setInterval(timeSet1,3000);
})
```

```css
#block2,
#block3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block2">
  <div>Block 2</div>
</div>
<div id="block3">
  <div>Block 3</div>
</div>
```